# Based on input value, place an associated object in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a collection of predefined input codes.  When an input code is entered in an input cell, I want to automatically post an associated object in an output cell.  For example, using the code table shown below:

1. Select A1.
2. Write `w5` in this cell.
3. Automatically, the color-filled, circled 5 object should appear in the adjacent cell.

[image: Example picture of what I would like to do]

Comment: You cannot copy the color with a formula.  But you can use multiple conditional formatting rules to check the table and format accordingly.  Or you could use an event-triggered macro

Comment: Use conditional formatting  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enter-and-format-data-fef13169-0a84-4b92-a5ab-d856b0d7c1f7#ID0EAABAAA=Conditional_formatting

Comment: @fixer1234: Excel formulas care values only, they completely ignore formatting.

Comment: Once you receive answers on a question, it isn't fair to the responders to alter the question in a way that invalidates their answers.

Comment: @fixer1234 your absolutely right , but witch answer exactly?

Comment: @fixer1234  so Now I understand what you mean, I did not intend to disrespect, but I changed it because I didn't receive the answer Sir.

Comment: The first comment here from Ron Rosenfeld is basically the answer.  You're creating objects.  Excel can display them, but you can't handle them like simple values, using formulas or functions.  It would be the same situation if you were using shapes or other display items that are not values.  You could record a macro for how to create each object.  Then use VBA to test the entered value and produce the associated object.

Comment: In your examples to date, the objects have not been completely random items, but had some relationship to the input.  Here, the circled number is the same as the numerical component of the input value.  In all examples the output color has matched an input color.  All of those details and rules would need to be part of creating the object.  But the color is ambiguous.  Input values don't have color unless you color them.  Is the color tied to the input code, or tied to a color you give the input value, which may vary from time to time?  (cont'd)

Comment: Your requirements are too ambiguous & broad to answer beyond this kind of very general advice. The purpose of the site is to share solutions to problems others may have. If you can express your problem in terms that will apply to more than just one variant of one personal problem, it can be useful to others. But it isn't useful for the site knowledge base to have a whole collection of questions that are minor variants of an odd problem that only you have. In other words, use questions to learn how to solve a class of problems for the future, rather than a coding service for your unique needs.

Comment: @fixer1234 Your comments contained 3 part: 
And I will response one by one.

Comment: @fixer1234 Part 1_ The Ron Rosenfeld’s answer is absolutely far from my question and when I saw nobody can understand it I said that in another way Ok? But now I believe you can’t get it too.

Comment: @fixer1234 Part 2_ Did I say anything about random? Who did? I don’t know why you are trying to say nonsense.
Of course the color should be same, this is my main request, and it should be same as the input cell. In excel everything is possible. If you don’t have ability to understand the question, please don’t condemn others.

Comment: @fixer1234 Part 3_ NOT AT ALL. My request was very explicit and clear. If your Mind couldn’t handle such a clear question, it’s not my fault. I don’t care what the damn purpose of this site. And also I don’t care to the others. I had a question and I thought this site can help. Now I see there is no expert here. And all I saw in these days just vain chatterbox with the doodle imbecile guys.

Answer (score 0):

*For the Small Data Set, what you are trying is worth using otherwise it's tedious job.*

Check the Screen Shot.

[image]

**To achieve the job I can suggest VBA Code also, but "Time Saver" is Conditional Formatting, follow these steps.**

1. Select both the Cells, where you write the Code to get Font Colour on ? mark.
2. Go to Conditional Formatting TAB.
3. Click New Rule.
4. From Select Rule Type & hit Last one from the List.
5. In Edit the Rule Description apply this =$A2="W1".
6. Hit the Format & apply the same Font, what W1 & it's adjacent Cell does have in the Table.
7. Repeat it for others.

**NB:** Replace ? mark with the Up Arrow.

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: In my Window I couldn't access to the Font format Y?

Comment: @Superstar,, check your screen shot,,,, Conditional Format is VISIBLE there !!!

Comment: @ Rajesh S , Please pay attention to me Bro! I mean I can NOT change the Font in the Conditional formatting. Please tell me how can I change the font in this window?

Comment: @Superstar,,, I've described all in steps, what else I can do here !! If possible write your valid mail Id.

Comment: @Superstar: discussing only on the answer and ignoring comments asking you for clarification won't help solving your issue. Please update your question with progress you made so far, and explain clearly your issue you're facing currently. " I can NOT change the Font in the Conditional formatting." - Why you can't change it? Have you looked tutorials on it?

Comment: @RajeshS: This is a site where we help each other, and also keep the answers public so others can learn from it too. Please don't drive the communication to private e-mails, besides jeopardising site's purpose there is a high chance OP won't be more clear there too.

Comment: @MátéJuhász ,, that I know very well, but you can see where the the OP has stuck up,, steps are listed along with Screen shot and is unable to solve it,, so that I told him,, write the ID,, and nothing,, :-)

Comment: @RajeshS: OP needs to take effort too, not just expect somebody works instead of him ...

Comment: @Rajesh ..exactly . please just show your respect to all the people instead of condemn them Máté Juhász . and If I knew my answer never I did send a post ,

Comment: @Máté Juhász , Furthermore I tried to understand what you mean, but as I did nothing changed. and I couldn't get the result.

Comment: @superstar: please update your question with exact steps you've tried and we can help further. Preferably add screenshots too.

Comment: @Máté Juhász I did update. Is there any answer for that?

Comment: @Superstar: again "please update your question with exact steps you've tried", you've got guidance, please follow it and ask specific questions if you can't manage to solve the problem. ...

Comment: 1. Select A1. 2.write w5 in this cell 3. Automatically when I write in cell A1, in the adjacent cell fill circled 5. Same format and other properties